# AnyLogic define speed for agents in Main

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I want to define speed aka velocity for ALL my agents in a parameter walkingSpeed inside main.
How do I access it from the "Initial velocity" settings inside the agent?

The [documentation](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/code/Access.html) recommended use of "Main().walkingSpeed" is not working :(

```
SetUp:
Main----------------------Patient
(has walkingSpeed)      |-Nurse
                        |-Internist
                        |-Surgeon
```

**Update 2014-08-01: Using get_Main also not working**

[image: anylogic error]

Comment: " is not working " Great, I know exactly what the problem is now...

Comment: Thanks James, the detailed error message "The method Main() is undefined for the type Internist. Location: Zana/Internist - Agent Type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have instances of the Agent Patient inside your Main. To access a parameter speed defined for Main, you would have to call: get_Main().speed

If you want to access other parameters of Agents inside Main from within Patien, you call: get_Main().otherAgent.get(i).otherParameter

If you want to access parameters of Agents inside Patient from within Patient, you can simply call: otherAgent.get(i).otherParameter, however it is recommended to go through the Main here anyway.

Comment: Sadly not working. I updated my question with a screenshot of the result. Any ideas what I did wrong? I also tried Variables!

Comment: Are your sure you have instances of your Patient Agent in your Main? Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: They are created by a source element inside Main. Is this enough?

Comment: No, then you would have to access the parameter through one of the currently created entities. I recommend the Anylogic book from the company founder for a first read on simulation. Some chapters are quite helpful, a look in the API for available methods is helpful too.

Comment: Since this is the correct answer to your question, I'd appreciate an upvote or respective mark. Thanks :)

Comment: I finally got the book! Can you give me a page and I upvote you ;)

Comment: That was more like a general recommendation :D I could have hooked you up with the corresponding page right away since I took a picture of it because it was so useful to me^^ p. 422

Comment: Thanks, also available at the [online help](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/code/Access.html).